# Переменная в переменной

Tags: python, django

Всем, привет! Как в шаблонизаторе вывести переменную в переменной:

```
 {%for k res%}
    <td>{{r.{{k.service_name}}}}</td>
 {%endfor%}
```

Answer (score 3):

Если название свойства объекта также является переменной, то придётся написать [свой фильтр](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/custom-template-tags/). Как-то так:

```
def get(obj, field):
    return getattr(obj, field, '')
```

и будет что-то вроде:

```
{%for k res%}
    <td>{{r|get:k.service_name}}</td>
{%endfor%}
```

Answer (score -1):

Можно так

```
k['service_name'] = 'asd'
k['foo']['bar'] = 'zxc'
```

и тогда можно делать так как

```
{{ k.service_name }}
{{ k.foo.bar }}
```

Comment: Это если названия известны во время разработки…